# Why is my ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET 10.2.4 failing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm trying to install ArcGIS_Runtime_SDK_DotNet_1024.exe. The installation appears to complete but then starts rolling back. The log file is not much help or I don't know how to read what it's saying.

ArcGIS 10.3 (desktop products only) is installed. OS is 64-bit Windows 8.1.

Any idea why this is failing or how I can troubleshoot further?

Installation Log File:

```
******************************

Processor type is : 64
The operating system is : Windows8.1 
The minimum operating system requirement has been met
Microsoft MSXML 6 installed on the machine: XML DOM Document 6.0
ArcGIS 10.1 for Server: NOT Installed

******************************
Input file : C:\tmp\ArcGISRuntimeSDKNET\SetupFiles\Setup.ini
Installer file : C:\tmp\ArcGISRuntimeSDKNET\SetupFiles\setup.msi
MSXML : NULL
Operating system: 64
Product Code : {28CC81FD-D0BB-4C59-9F3F-EC8594E6FD00}
Product Name : ArcGIS Runtime SDK 10.2.4 for the Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft Sql CLR Types x86: NULL
Microsoft Sql CLR Types x64: NULL
Microsoft Windows Installer : NULL
Windows Operating System : Windows8.1


******************************
Input file : C:\tmp\ArcGISRuntimeSDKNET\SetupFiles\Setup.ini
Installer file : C:\tmp\ArcGISRuntimeSDKNET\SetupFiles\setup.msi
MSXML : NULL
Operating system: 64
Product Code : {28CC81FD-D0BB-4C59-9F3F-EC8594E6FD00}
Product Name : ArcGIS Runtime SDK 10.2.4 for the Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft Sql CLR Types x86: NULL
Microsoft Sql CLR Types x64: NULL
Microsoft Windows Installer : NULL
Windows Operating System : Windows8.1

Product was installed unsuccessfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation process, be sure only the versions of Visual Studio actually installed are selected. For whatever reason, the installer selected versions of VS not installed and I just went with the defaults. That was the cause of the failed installs. VS 2012 (I think that's the version) was selected but not actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get more info by running the msi with verbose logging.  When you run the ArcGIS_Runtime_SDK_DotNet_1024.exe I believe it extracts to, by default `'C:\Users\your user name\Documents\ArcGIS 10.2.4'`, but you might have selected a different location given the log info above (c:\tmp).

So where ever the msi is on your system open a cmd prompt and run the msi as per these resources [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126077/create-an-msi-log-file) and\or [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300/en-us)

From the default location this would be:

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\Documents\ArcGIS 10.2.4\ArcGISRuntimeSDKNET\SetupFiles> msiexec /l*v "log.log" /i setup.msi
```

The output log.log from the above run should have more information that might point to the issue.